# Creating a new row in other table when a specific column is updated in dataBase

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database I want to set a trigger that happened after updating on a specific column in the first table, then inserting a new row on the third table that is taking the data from the other two tables is that possible to set it?
and how I can make it on SQL server

**For example, this is my first table**

```
create table ordered_by(
OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,MemberID int, isClean BOOL, barCode int,
FOREIGN KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES Members(MemberID),
FOREIGN KEY (barCode) REFERENCES Products(barCode) );
```

**the second table**

```
create table FINE( Fine_id int not null primary key,
type varchar(10), 
amount float not null, orderID int,
FOREIGN KEY (orderID) REFERENCES ordered_by(orderID));
```

**The third table** that I want to insert the data inside it after updating on the isClean column in the first table

```
create table debit (memberID int , FineID int , type varchar(10), amount float);
```

> so the third table will be empty unless the updating is set  then I
>   want to select the memberID, FineID, Type, the amount from first and
>   second table then insert them in the third table  how is that could be
>   done in code?

Comment: You''re looking for an MSSQL [trigger](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers//)

Comment: There is no relation between ordered_by table and FINE table?